# When working with pointers in C, when and why do we need to use malloc?

Tags: c

```
 /* Note: The returned array must be malloced,
    assume caller calls free(). */
int* twoSum(int* nums, int numsSize, int target) {
    int *ans; //why error
    for(int i = 0; i < numsSize; i++){
        for(int j = i+1; j < numsSize; j++){
            if(nums[i] + nums[j] == target){
                ans[0] = i;
                ans[1] = j;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return ans;
}
```

Why code above is incorrect and code below correct (with `malloc` added)?

```
 /* Note: The returned array must be malloced,
    assume caller calls free(). */
int* twoSum(int* nums, int numsSize, int target) {
    int *ans = (int*)malloc(2*sizeof(int)); //why not error
    for(int i = 0; i < numsSize; i++){
        for(int j = i+1; j < numsSize; j++){
            if(nums[i] + nums[j] == target){
                ans[0] = i;
                ans[1] = j;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return ans;
}
```

Comment: Could you please put code inside your questionm, not as picture?

Comment: sorry sir, i've edited it.

Comment: As an aside: [Do I cast the result of malloc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc) **No.**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you don't assign anything to `ans`, it contains some garbage value.  Attempting to dereference the pointer (i.e. access what the pointer points to), which using an array index is implicitly doing, means you're trying to read/write some arbitrary memory location you're not supposed to.

Trying to use an invalid pointer invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).  This means your program may crash, it may output strange results, or it may appear to work properly.  Also, making a seemingly unrelated change such as an extra call to `printf` for debugging, adding an unused variable, or compiling with different optimization settings can change how undefined behavior manifests itself.

So just because the program *seems* to be behaving properly doesn't mean there isn't a problem.  It just means it will probably show up later when you least expect it.

A pointer needs to point to some valid memory location before you can use it.  Calling `malloc` allocates a block of memory and returns a pointer to that memory.  After assigning that address to `ans`, you can then use it to read/write the memory that was allocated.  This guarantees that your program will be well defined.

Comment: Thank u! you mean that i must calling malloc when i define pointer?  but sometimes i just define the pointer like "int *p;"  it also can be used. why

Comment: @Suprit_young  See my edit.  Just because it "works" doesn't mean it always will.

Comment: i understand, Thank you very much!